# Group mysql query by months or weeks with proper start/endings

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have searched and viewed a lot of answers on SO but even trying to apply all I found I get incorrect results.

I am trying to group my mysql results by week mon-sun, and by month from day 1 to last day of month

I have tried different types of grouping like:

```
GROUP BY YEARWEEK(data)
GROUP BY WEEK(data)
```

for weeks and

```
GROUP BY MONTH(data)
```

for months

all these grouping methods return uncorrect groupings. some results start in random days of the month or the week.

this is example query which get results from last month entries divided by week although the week grouping is not resulting in weeks from mon-sun.

```
SELECT *, count(id) AS count FROM leadz WHERE YEAR(data) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND MONTH(data) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) GROUP BY YEARWEEK(data)
```

these are the week segments I get as results:

```
 2016-07-01   2016-07-04   2016-07-16    2016-07-17   2016-07-25   2016-07-31
```

Next is a sample query of total entries grouped by month, again gropuing does not start from 1st of the month

```
SELECT *, count(id) AS count FROM leadz GROUP BY MONTH(data)
```

these are the month segments I get as result:

```
2016-04-18    2016-05-25    2016-06-01    2016-07-25   2016-08-02
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

For starting on monday you should use

```
YEARWEEK(data, 1)
```

or

```
WEEK(data,1)
```

see  this for ref  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week

so your select should be

```
SELECT *, count(id) AS count 
FROM leadz 
WHERE YEAR(data) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
AND MONTH(data) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
GROUP BY YEARWEEK(data, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but still get odd results for weeks, and does not solve the month grouping